# paypal ipn always invalid

Tags: php, api, paypal

### **Paypal ipn always return invalid**

Hi everyone, i'm stuck with this problem from a week. What I'm trying to do is to pass a variable in php containing all the data of a pdf via paypal button in order to be processed on my page later. So here's my code generated by paypal where i've added notify_url and custom variable.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="AEJ7FLWRMAK44">
  <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://mysite.it/ipn_listener.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php $base; ?>">
  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/it_IT/IT/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal è il metodo rapido e sicuro per pagare e farsi pagare online.">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/it_IT/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

The variable $base contains all the data of the PDF created in this page,i need to pass them through paypal form.
 And here the code of the listener(Directly from paypal).

```
    <?php
    require('fpdf.php');
    // CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
    // Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
    // Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
    define("DEBUG", 1);
    // Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
    define("USE_SANDBOX", 0);
    define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");
    // Read POST data
    // reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
    // issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
// Without this step anyone can fake IPN data
if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}
$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
if(DEBUG == true) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}
// CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
// Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
// CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
// of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
// This is mandatory for some environments.
//$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
    {
    if(DEBUG == true) { 
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
} else {
        // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
}
echo $res;
// Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
// Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment and mark item as paid.
    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $plan = $_POST ['$custom'];
    $plan -> Output('filename.pdf','D');
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
    // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
}
?>
```

and this is the log that result after pay:

```
[2015-12-13 13:06 UTC] HTTP request of validation request:POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1
Host: www.paypal.com
Accept: */*
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 for IPN payload: cmd=_notify-validate
[2015-12-13 13:06 UTC] HTTP response of validation request: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Paypal-Debug-Id: 3c9689e4c464d
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
DC: dcg11-origin-www-2.paypal.com
Date: Sun, 13 Dec 2015 13:06:48 GMT
Content-Length: 7
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: cwrClyrK4LoCV1fydGbAxiNL6iG=h1DUElHT0plodZm1lFPnTdqF1LiGzLoXG7dYHHRSRG9RL2cia6MdmQ6MahF1Zv2nJHPi_OHvGTI9k7icIO_xteZXVKW6_1Eanm2OzV6EUhqfCx5RaJVVZ0k6kREma-fge47I2jdAUVmGU3WkpxycLClRTtW4yxG7Upafo701Ey7HFKhzN9Q9h0FlegIaInROJAbI6it8h-Mvg-2rOIsVPBRkIJ132Jmyg0Yg0-Gi0_gQjnixauCWZ8J3yrCA_--4FroiKAAF5oRfqVPwGs9nmUOMA7nPwgSf0HHZQ6uCJ7LSUkfU3ezY77NrNaLnnEpZQ59MNutMaQeR5Blt3aAKCVQdOKicNO7ilgSho4_MygvMVCsUxcDhmlFaGE5KmkkYHdRW7MpIXivjpwSf987gDNope3f8dyq06XXnMeBMiCNhpKlh5BclrWcI7Cm; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Wed, 10-Dec-2025 13:06:48 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navcmd=_notify-validate; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navlns=0.0; expires=Tue, 12-Dec-2017 13:06:48 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DLIVE9.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dappdispatcher%26TIME%3D1735224662; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Set-Cookie: Apache=10.16.1.3.1450012007804246; path=/; expires=Tue, 05-Dec-45 13:06:47 GMT
Set-Cookie: AKDC=dcg11-origin-www-2.paypal.com; expires=Sun, 13-Dec-2015 13:36:48 GMT; path=/; secure
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000

INVALID
[2015-12-13 13:06 UTC] Invalid IPN: cmd=_notify-validate
```

I've activated IPN in my paypal account but i've always return invalid, also by deleting the piece of code that sends and receives the variable custom the result does not change. Can somebody help me? this problem is giving me a headache for a week. Thanks in advance to all for answers.